# WordPress Child Theme JavaScript File Not Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

can some please check the following code and kindly tell me why the CUSTOM-SCRIPT.JS file isn't loading. The CUSTOM-STYLES.CSS is loading but the script file isn't. The code I am referring to is at the bottom FUNCTION CUSTOM_STYLES() but I thought the code above must be important.

```
    <?php

function bean_feature_setup()
{
    $args = array(
        'primary' => array(
            'adminstyles'       => true, 

            'customizer'        => true, 
            'meta'              => true,
            'seo'               => true,        
            'widgets'           => true, 
            'widgetareas'       => true, 
            'whitelabel'        => false,
            'updates'           => false,
            ),
        'plugins' => array(
            'notice'            => true,
            'portfolio'         => true,
            'shortcodes'        => true,
            'twitter'           => true,
            'instagram'         => true,
            'social'            => true,
            'pricingtables'     => true,
          ),   
        'comments' => array(
            'pages'             => false,
            'portfolio'         => false,
            'posts'             => true,
            ),
        'debug' => array(
            'footer'            => false,
            'queries'           => false,
            ),   
        );
    return apply_filters( 'bean_theme_config_args', $args );
}
add_action('bean_init', 'bean_feature_setup');

?>

    <?php
function custom_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('custom_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/custom-styles.css', array(),'', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/custom-script.js', array('jQuery'),'', false);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','custom_styles');

?>
```

Comment: should be easy to figure out from browser console network tab... is the path of script file pointing to a stylesheet directory??

Comment: The custom-styles.css file is loading, the custom-script.js file doesn't even show in the console.

Comment: well what directory is it in? Above suggests it's in css directory which doesn't make sense

Comment: It's in child theme root directory, just where child theme's style.css is located.

Comment: js in a css directory? Why?

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood, I said it's in the theme's root directory, so if the theme folder is koi-child then the javascript file is in koi-child > custom-javascript.js.

Comment: then change that in your code `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`

Comment: Can you please give an example of what I should change it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `jQuery` to `jquery`

```
 wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/custom-script.js', array('jquery'),'', false);
```

Comment: Sorry initially I had it jquery but since that wasn't working I changed it to see if jQuery works, so that's not the problem.

Comment: try removing dependency then. try only `array()` and see if it will be added

Comment: also, make sure `custom-script` is not been use by other `wp_enqueue_script` function

Comment: Thanks SilverKenn, changed the name of the script file to custom-coded-scripts.js and it worked. I had checked the script files via Firebug and there was no other file name custom-script.js, so not sure why it didn't load. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Welcome. the script handle you use might been used by other functions that only executes with conditions. you should check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is ;)

Comment: Actually, I didn't change the script handle it is still 'custom-script', just changed the script file name.